# Regex to check file name

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regex query to verify a name of file and make sure that it contains only English characters, numbers or these characters [,],-, _

However it should not allow characters like these: 
Ã¿Â¿Ã¿Â¿Ã¿Â¿Ã¿Â¿Ã¿Â¿Ã¿Â¿Ã¿Â¿Ã¿Â³J

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9.\[\]_-]+$
```

I've added the dot as a possibility, other than that the above requires at least one ASCII letter, digit, square bracket, underscore or dash (minus sign).

Answer (score 1):

The regex looks like this:

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9\[\]\-_]+$/
```

Note that this does not allow empty strings ;)

Comment: Remember that this only matches A to Z, a to z, [, ], -, and _.

Comment: Remember that this was the requirement?

Comment: Forgive me for my sloppy sarcasm. Were you talking about the dot (because of the filename requirement)?